Tab function not working, second tab text is at the bottom
I'm trying to make tabs to maximise space, the pages themselves work, but the text on the second page is at the bottom. I'm assuming the text is being layed out like it's the continuation of the text on the first tab. I haven't played with the third tab because it's more of the same thing, but this time the text is fully outside the box and explodes the rest of the annoying layout.
I've tried changing text position, changing margin, chat gpt didn't manage to fix it, and i tried looking at another bit of code (premade by someone else) and i couldn't figure out what they did that i hadn't. I'm still very much new to coding, and because of the site i'm coding on only allows for HTML, help would be GREATLY apreciated...
 <div class="card rounded-0 mx-1 my-auto align-self-stretch" 
      style="height:320px; width:450px; 
            background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a8/80/31/a88031d38378d6a22afa1524bddc4e90.jpg); 
            background-size:cover; 
            background-position:center; 
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-color:#1c1a1b;
            
            color: #1c1a1b; 
            letter-spacing:1px; 
            font-weight: 600;">
 
  
<ul class="nav row no-gutters justify-content-around text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase" 
    style="letter-spacing: 1px;">
  
    <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1 active" data-toggle="tab" href="#ONE" style="color:#423d40;">
    Info</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#TWO" style="color:#423d40;">
    Likes & dislikes</a></li>

    <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#THREE" style="color:#423d40;">
    meow</a></li>
    
</ul>

          
          
          
          
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active show" data-toggle="tab" id="ONE">
          
         <p style="font-family:courier; text-align:center; font-weight:550; font-size:25px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">  meow  </p>
         
          
         <p style="font-family:courier; text-align:left; font-weight:400; font-size:18px; margin-left:10px;" >  
            
            
             <b> ★ nicknames </b>      meowable
            
            <br> <b> ★ pronouns </b>       meowable
            
            <br> <b> ★ age </b>               meowable
            
            <br> <b> ★ species </b>        meowable
            
            <br> <b> ★ occupation </b>      meowable
            
            <br> <b> ★ playlist </b>       <a href="   " target="_BLANK"> meowable </a>   
        
        </p> 
           
    </div> 
         
         
          
         
    <div class="tab-pane fade" data-toggle="tab" id="TWO">
          
  
  <p style="font-family:courier; text-align:center; font-weight:550; font-size:25px; position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"> meow </p>
          
          <p style="font-family:courier; text-align:left; font-weight:400; font-size:18px; margin-left:10px;" >  
            
            
             <b> ★ meow </b>      meowable
           
           
         </div> 
         </div> 
    </div>


I hope the below helps:


// Get all the tab links
let tabLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

// Get all the tab panes
let tabPanes = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane');

// Initially hide all tab panes
tabPanes.forEach(pane => {
    pane.style.display = 'none';
});

// Show the first tab pane
tabPanes[0].style.display = 'block';

// Add click event listener to each tab link
tabLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Hide all tab panes
        tabPanes.forEach(pane => {
            pane.style.display = 'none';
        });

        // Show the clicked tab pane
        tabPanes[index].style.display = 'block';
    });
});
.card {
    height:320px; 
    width:450px;
    background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a8/80/31/a88031d38378d6a22afa1524bddc4e90.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#1c1a1b;
    color: #1c1a1b;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.nav {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.nav-link {
    color:#423d40;
}
  <div class="card rounded-0 mx-1 my-auto align-self-stretch">

        <ul class="nav row no-gutters justify-content-around text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase">

            <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1 active" data-toggle="tab" href="#ONE">
                Info</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#TWO">
                Likes & dislikes</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item col-auto"><a class="nav-link px-1" data-toggle="tab" href="#THREE">
                meow</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div class="tab-pane fade in active show" data-toggle="tab" id="ONE">
            <span>Tab 1 content</span>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" data-toggle="tab" id="TWO">
            <span>Tab 2 content</span>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" data-toggle="tab" id="THREE">
            <span>Tab 3 content</span>
        </div>
    </div>




Is there no way to do this using only HTML? I've seen other codes manage it but I can't spot what i've done wrong...
